# Loading Google Map into Colorbox AJAX loaded content

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-maps, colorbox

I have a page that loads several markers onto a google map at
http://solarpanelhost.org/garden/

When you click on a marker it uses Colorbox to make an AJAX call

```
// locations is a multi dimensional array containing lat/lon/URL
// for the markers and ajax call

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i){
    return function() {
        $.colorbox({
            href: locations[i][3]
            ,width: '80%'
            ,height: '80%'
            ,onComplete: singleMap(locations[i][0], locations[i][1], 'project_map_single', icon, 8)
        });
    }
})(locations, i));


function singleMap(lat, lon, id, icon, zoom) {
    icon = typeof icon !== 'undefined' ? icon : 'logo-flower-icon.png';
    zoom = typeof zoom !== 'undefined' ? zoom : 8;
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: zoom
        ,center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon)
        ,mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(id), myOptions);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng
        ,map: map
        ,icon: '/static/images/'+icon
    });
}
```

I'm having trouble getting the Google Map to load using the onComplete callback
getting error

```
a is null -- main.js (line 30)
```

main.js is the google maps main script

looked it up and it seems the issue is that Google Maps is not finding the element when it tries to initialize -- I continued to see this same error after adding the call with a delay by binding with setTimeout

```
$(document).bind('cbox_complete', function(){
    setTimeout(singleMap(36, -105, 'project_map_single'), 10000);
});
```

any ideas?

would rather not resort to static images though I'm not seeing much else by way of options

Answer (score 2):

to embed the map into colorbox add the option "&output=embed" at the end of the generated url

if you are using iframe method of colorbox (sorry for my english)

```
<a href="http://maps.google.com/maps/generatedurl...&output=embed" class="gmap">gmap<a>
```

Answer (score 1):

This probably isn't the solution to the problem you are having, but the following is wrong:

```
onComplete: singleMap(locations[i][0], locations[i][1], 'project_map_single', icon, 8)
```

This would immediately execute the singleMap function, and return it's value to the onComplete property.  You want to pass onComplete a function to execute, not the return value of a function.  So you would do something like this instead:

```
onComplete: function(){ singleMap(locations[i][0], locations[i][1], 'project_map_single', icon, 8); }
```

If you still get an error, it shouldn't be because #project_map_single was unable to be located.  Double check the markup that is being displayed in colorbox to verify that an element with that ID is actually there.

Comment: that was definitely part of the issue -- the script now throws the error -- Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null -- if I add -- ,size: new google.maps.Size(300, 300) -- to the singleMap script myOptions then it gives me an undefined function error